# Missing types on firebase auth lib

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, types, firebase-authentication

For some reason I can't seem to find the appropriate types for `firebase`.

When creating a fresh project in typescript, e.g. `npx create-react-app test --template typescript`, and after installing both `firebase` and `@types/firebase`, I get a:

```
Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/username/test/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index")'.
```

When trying to call it as:

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

firebase.auth();
```

I also tried with:

- `import firebase from "firebase/app"; // Same error as above`
- `import firebase from "firebase"; // Cannot find module 'firebase' or its corresponding type declarations.`
- Adding a `import "firebase/auth"` as suggested in some docs, but nothing

I'm on latest versions, and so:

```json
"firebase": "^9.1.0", // Dependency
"@types/firebase": "^3.2.1" // Dev dependency
```

Can it be I perhaps need to install a different `@types/` package? Or perhaps the two versions contain mismatched typings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the new Modular Syntax which was introduced from `V9.0.0`. The new syntax looks like:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"

const app = initializeApp({...config})

const auth = getAuth(app)

export { auth }
```

If you want to use existing name-spaced syntax, then you can use `compat` versions:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
```

I'd recommend following the [upgrading to new Modular syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk) and following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) which has examples of both the syntaxes. Also checkout [this Firecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQvOAnNvcNQ) to learn more about the new SDK.

Comment: That is it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm still having problems with this as well even using the new modular syntax, I'm not getting any type support in my IDE like I'd normally expect. I did bring in @firebase/app-types but the documentation says you shouldn't have to interact with these packages directly, please advise.

Comment: Don't add replies to answers or questions as separate answers. Instead write it out as a comment to whatever you're replying to.

Comment: What are the versions you use for `firebase` and `@types/firebase`? Also, what error are you getting? And where?